# Why reference to bootstrap's CSS and JS is invalid in the JSP file of maven?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, maven, jsp

[two way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xgSt.png)

i tried above two ways，but it doesn't work. if you know please let me know. thank you !
and follow is my running result :[running result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLi2A.png), and my project's request path[request path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0Vy6.png)

Comment: Provide the code where you tried this and we may be able to help

Comment: my framework is springmvc.here is my code，and this is my frist time ask question in stackoverflow .so i don't know how display my code.i am so sorry!